# Is this exceptional case, where pronoun "his" not referred to "last male person" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

In [Runaway Jury (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Jury), Plaintiff attorney Rohr shows a weapon to Mr. Murphy, who own and operate Excalibur Guns:

> Rohr: Would you tell us about your arrangement... ...with Michael
> Kincaid, who illegally sold this Performa 990 semiautomatic... ...to
> Kevin Peltier smack-dab out of the trunk of **his** car.

Is this exceptional case, where pronoun "his" not referred to "last male person" in a sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not say it is "exceptional," no.

*Usually* the pronoun refers to the closest noun before it in the sentence. However, it has to make sense in context. Here the pronoun "his" must, of course, refer to a previously-mentioned man. As you point out, "his" does not refer to Kevin Peltier, because it wouldn't make sense for Kevin to be sold guns "out of" *his own* car's trunk. So "his" must refer to Michael Kincaid.